# Mariadb : disable unused engines

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb, myisam

I am using **Mariadb** on Debian. I noticed that mysqld process is using almost **1GB of RAM** so i wanted to tune it up, I tried to disable MyISAM engine since I don't use it but I could not do it:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT engine,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT TABLE_SCHEMA) Table_Schema_List,COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables GROUP BY engine;
+--------------------+------------------------------------+----------+
| engine             | Table_Schema_List                  | COUNT(*) |
+--------------------+------------------------------------+----------+
| Aria               | information_schema,mysql           |       18 |
| InnoDB             | mysql,phpmyadmin,xxxx,xxxx         |       59 |
| MEMORY             | information_schema                 |       64 |
| PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA | performance_schema                 |       52 |
+--------------------+------------------------------------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

MariaDB version :

```
mysql -V
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.15-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

What I've done:

First, I changed the engine to InnoDB/Aria on all databases **SEE ABOVE** and I tried to disable MYISAM, I added :

```
[mysqld]
skip-myisam
```

Output error:

```
... [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ambiguous option '--skip-myisam' (--skip-myisam-block-size)
... [ERROR] Parsing options for plugin 'MyISAM' failed.
```

I also tried to use the following variable

```
disabled_storage_engines="MyISAM,MRG_MyISAM,CSV"
```

but it is unknown

```
... [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown variable 'disabled_storage_engines=MyISAM,MRG_MyISAM,CSV'
```

anyone can help me?

What I want is to **reduce RAM usage** by MYSQLD

I use mariadb *only* for **roundcube** and **postfix**

***Any help or explanation is appreciated***

Regards

Comment: Find another explanation for the memory use.  It is **not** being caused by the unused storage engines.

Comment: That's why I'm here, I need help to find out what causing that.

For a start, I wanted to disable MyISAM and recheck the memory usage, but I can't disable it...

Comment: `SELECT @@KEY_BUFFER_SIZE, @@INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_SIZE;`.  What are the values?  Additionally, does this memory consumption begin at server startup or is it growing dramatically ovet time?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot

KEY_BUFFER_SIZE 134217728 ||
INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_SIZE 268435456 ||

it begins at the startup.

Comment: Well, I see the part of the problem.  It looks like someone has been "tuning" your server.  Delete `key_buffer_size` from your configuration file.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thank you, I googled key_buffer_size and found out that it was related to MyISAM, AND "free -m" shows me that 700MB of ram is being buffered/cached. I am still searching about why is that. **one more question please**, I changed tables engine of "mysql" database from MyISAM to InnoDB and some of them didnt want to change to InnoDB i think it was due to table structure, so I did put Aria, qst: **is that safe?**

Comment: "700MB is being buffered/cached" does not matter.  What the OS reports as buff/cache *is still free memory in the sense that matters, see [Linux Ate My Ram](https://www.linuxatemyram.com).  Also, tampering with the tables in the "mysql" schema is not supported, and not safe.  Put them back as you found them, if possible... then take a full backup with `mysqldump` if possible, and restart the server to make sure it actually can successfully restart.

Comment: Also, see [XY](http://xyproblem.info).  It's very important on this site (but admittedly not always easy) to present your question without any of your initial assumptions assumed to be correct.  The buff/cache thing stumps a lot of people.  Also see the pull-quote [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/45570/11651) that  talks about the potential harm of excessively "tuning" MySQL Server (includes MariaDB).  Most of the defaults sre best left alone.

Comment: I have already done a backup before touching the "mysql" database. 
Thank you so much..